# i can't type my answer using cin in visual studio code it says enter your age but it says read-only text editor how do I fix that?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

## include

```
using namespace std;

int main()

{


int name;
int respone;

cout << "enter your name:  ";
cin >> name;

cout << "hello " << name << "how are you today ";
cin >> respone;
cout << "ok"
```

> quote cant use answer my question that i ask myself on the code

```
}
```

Comment: Hi couple of things you should import <iostram> and import <string>. Also i am assuming name is a string and the response also looks like a string. See if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify your code as follows to make it work in the expected manner

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string name;
    string response;

    cout << "Enter your name:  ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Hello " << name << ", how are you today?" << endl;
    cin >> response;

    cout << "OK" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, you need to include the `<iostream>` header so that you can use `std::cout` and `std::cin`. Also note that both `name` and `response` variables should be of type `std::string` since the expected responses would be character strings. Finally, you are missing a semicolon after your last `cout` statement, and should `return 0` from the main function.

C++ can be a challenging language to learn, as I have found while contributing in a small way to an open source AGI research project ([RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org)). A good reference book that I have been using is [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) by Bjarne Stroustroup, the creator of the C++ language.

I would also suggest from my own experience that while learning C++, you would benefit a lot by typing in your code in a text editor and invoking the compiler from the command line instead of relying on and IDE such as Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    string respone;

    cout << "enter your name:  ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "hello " << name << "how are you today ";
    cin >> respone;
    cout << "ok";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solve it:

1. Go to extension and download Code Runner.
2. Go to preference and search for 'code runner'.
3. Scroll down until you find "Code-runner: Run In Terminal" and make sure it's actives.

That's it.